# Determining the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x^{\alpha_i}}$

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, generating-functions, computational-complexity

I looking for an algorithm to efficiently find the value$\mod p$ of the coefficient of $x^n$ in a generating function of this form:

$$\prod_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{1-x^{\alpha_i}}$$

where $p$ is some prime of order $2^m$.

What I mean by efficiently: it may be polynomial in $m$, and must be at most logarithmic in $n$ (so basically is must just be polynomial in the input size).

Due to the simple nature of this expression I would imagine that such an algorithm might exist.

Comment: Well,  there are computer programs to perform such calculations besed on MacMahon algorithm.

Comment: @Leox can you give some more details? A google search for this algorithm does not result in anything that seems to be clearly related to this problem

Comment: Shouldn't the title be $\prod_{i=1}^m$ instead of $\prod_{i=1}^n$

Comment: Yes you are right, changed

Comment: Sorry,  it is not MacMahon algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^n$ is called the Hilbert polynomial. 
It can be calculated, see the book R. Stanley, Enumerative combinatorics. Vol. 1., Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics. 49. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. (1999).

See the  Theorem 4.1.1 and Proposition 4.1.1  of the book.

Related sofware see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3290.pdf)

I sure those calculation can be adapted for the modular case.
Since all reduced to solving of system of linear equations  the complexity of the algorithm is polynomial.

Let

$$
\dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-z^{\alpha_i})}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H(n,\alpha)x^n
$$

Here is some examples

$$
H(n,1,1,1)=1/2\,{n}^{2}+3/2\,n+1,\\
H(n,1,2,3)=1/12\,{n}^{2}+1/2\,n+1/8\,\cos \left( \pi \,n \right) +2/9\,\cos
\left( 2/3\,\pi \,n \right) +{\frac {47}{72}}
$$

Comment: Just to be sure: is this at most logarithmic in $n$?

Comment: Well, I think it is about $n^2.$

Comment: Hm well then I can't use it unfortunately

Comment: The complexity is the same as the complexity of an algorithn of solution of system of linear equations.

Comment: Accepted this answer because I realise now that there does not seem to be any better solution then this one. Thanks for the effort of finding all this information for me!